# How to use "Corpus of Contemporary American English"

Tags: discussion

How to make proper *inputs* for [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/)? I mean those *inputs* like "no [n*] [vvz]", when you can search for different forms of speech (nouns / verbs /...), and for different forms of a verb, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is explained on http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/help/syntax_e.asp, while the tokens to use (the strings between brackets) for the parts of speech are listed on http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/claws7tags.html.

Comment: kiam, but the OP is asking "How to make ... ", not "Where do I find ...", no?

Comment: It's like when somebody asks "How do I write a proper C++ program?" You give them the link to the page explaining the C++ syntax. `:)`